# Javascript - Etapas de configurações

Tags: javascript

Estou com um problema que é: preciso que ao iniciar, meu aplicativo faça uma série de configurações.

Eu tentei fazer usando maquina de estados, e acabei encontrando essa: https://github.com/jakesgordon/javascript-state-machine/

Só que ela não me permite escolher pra onde eu quero que próxima etapa vá, somente na inicialização eu consigo definir isso:

```
events: [           
        { name: 'start', from: ['none', 'getInformations'], to: 'getInformations' },
        { name: 'getInformations', from: 'getInformations', to: 'getTuner' },
        { name: 'getTuner', from: 'getTuner', to: 'getNetworkInfo' },
        { name: 'getNetworkInfo', from: 'getNetworkInfo', to: 'none' }
      ],
```

No caso, quando alguma etapa der erro, eu não consigo voltar pra ela porque já foi definido pra onde ela iria ir.

Eu realmente preciso criar uma etapa de configuração que eu tenha a flexibilidade de escolher pra onde quero ir e que respeite chamadas assíncronas. Alguém tem alguma dica de como fazer isso? Sem usar maquina de estados, a unica solução que consigo pensar é:

```
    while (validacao) {
        switch(estado) {
             case: 0:
                 fazAlgumaCoisa();
                 break;
              case 1:
                  fazOutraCoisa();
                  break;
        }
        }

fazAlgumaCoisa() {
   http.get('blablabla:8080').succes(){
     estado = 1;
}
}
```

Mas não vejo isso como uma solução elegante.. Se alguém poder me dar uma luz, agradeço muito.

**EDIT**: Digamos que tenho 4 passos que são obrigatórios pra fazer minha aplicação funcionar e preciso executar um após outro:

passo1 -> passo2 -> passo3 -> passo4

Porém, no passo 2, obtive um erro e preciso faze-lo ir para o passo 2 de novo.

Como eu poderia fazer isso?

**EDIT2**: Depois de algumas lidas em vários lugares, cheguei nesse código (apenas exemplos ilustrativos):

```
    var nextState = 'stopped';

var states = {

    stopped : function() {
        console.log("in stopped");
        nextState = 'started';

    },

    started : function() {
        console.log("in started");
        nextState = 'finished';
    },

    finished: function () {
        console.log("in finished");
        nextState = 'finished';
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
};

var interval = setInterval(function() {
    states[nextState]();
}, 300);
```

Não tenho certeza se isso é uma prática boa e como se comporta na memória, mas me parece uma solução agradável, tendo em vista que o setInterval vai ser destruído quando chegar na ultima etapa. Além disso, o acesso as funções será extremamente rápidas já que estou passando o índice correto para o array que contém minhas instruções.

Comment: Não entendi muito bem o que você está querendo fazer. Você pode dar um exemplo concreto? (Muito provavelmente você não precisa de máquina de estados pra fazer o que você quer mas a pergunta é toda sobre máquina de estados)

Comment: Provavelmente eu não precise, mas não consigo pensar em outra solução no momento..

Answer (score 2):

Você pode escrever sua máquina de estados "na mão" usando funções mutualmente recursivas:

```
function faz_coisas(onDone){

    function passo1(){
        umaCoisaAssincrona(function(result){
          blah();
          passo2();
        });
    }

    function passo2(){
        ajax({
           onsuccess: passo3,
           onerror: passo2
        });
    }

    function passo3(){
        outracoisa(function(){
            onDone(meu_resultado);
        });
    }

    passo1();
}

//chamando o inicializador:
faz_coisas(function(result){
   console.log("tá tudo pronto");
});
```

A maneira básica de escrever funções assíncronas em Javascript é através de algo chamado "continuation passing style": suas funções chamam uma função continuação ao invés de retornarem valores normalmente. No caso de passo1, passo2 e passo3, em que o próximo passo é sempre o mesmo isso é bem simples (basta chamar a função de próximo passo diretamente) mas no caso de funções reutilizáveis como "fazer_coisas" você não sabe a priori qual função roda depois de você acabar. O que você pode fazer, então é receber essa continuação como parâmetro (o nosso "onDone").

---

Agora umas questões mais avançadas: escrevendo o código em continuation-passing-style nós conseguimos fazer qualquer coisa que quisermos. No entando, o nosso programa fica bem menos estruturado feio e chato de escrever - por exemplo, o loop do passo2 tem que ser feito com uma chamada recursiva ao invés de com um while. De uma certa forma, podemos dizer que continuation-passing-style é uma forma bem baixo nível de se programar.

Se você quiser algo mais alto nível e estruturado, você pode dar uma olhada em alguma biblioteca de programação assíncrona (que usa callbacks ou *promisses*) ou, algo que para mim é o ideal, use um preprocessador de código que extenda a sintaxe de Javascript com *generators*.

Comment: Em relação a recursividade, isso não gera de problemas de memória ? A aplicação no qual estou envolvendo isso é embarcada, e nosso hardware é meio antigo, com poucos recursos...

Vou editar minha pergunta e apresentar algo que cheguei a pensar, você poderia me dizer se é uma abordagem boa ?

Comment: Não tem problema se as funções estiverem sendo usadas sempre de forma assíncrona. Por exemplo, se o próximo passo estiver sempre depois de um setTimeout ou chamada ajax

Comment: Btw, porque vocês estão usando JS para uma aplicação embarcada? Na minha opinião seria mais apropriado usar algo como Lua. Lua é bem mais leve que Javascript, interage mais facilmente com C ou outras linguagens, tem recursão de cauda (dá pra fazer funções recursivas que nunca estouram a pilha) e corrotinas (dá pra programar de forma assíncrona sem ter que usar callbacks).

Comment: Porque temos a necessidade de carregar mídias feita em HTML.. No caso, exibir um .html e carregar os eventos contido neste. É possível fazer isso usando LUA?

Comment: Bem, os eventos dentro do html estão escritoes em Javascript então a coisa complica...